# Can I use CBPairingAgent unpairPeer: to remove the bluetooth device from paired

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

I want to remove paired bluetooth device from system settings or "unpair". I know that apple doesn't provide public api to do this so I tried private class `CBPairingAgent`. I found headers on github
[CBCentralManager.h](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CBCentralManager.h)
[CBPairingAgent.h](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CBPairingAgent.h) and here is my code:

```
- (void)unpair:(CBPeripheral *)peer {
    id agent = [self.centralManager valueForKey:@"sharedPairingAgent"];
//    [agent performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self.centralManager];
    [agent performSelector:@selector(unpairPeer:) withObject:peer];
}
```

This code runs without errors but also without any effect for peripheral.

Can somebody point me in right direction? Or suggest better way

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @JBA nope, I think this code is not working because my app doesn't have right entitlements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private API to remove a device pairing works if the process has enough entitlements, which is only possible on a JB device.

On JB, I've added these entitlements (found in Settings & SpringBord):

- com.apple.BTServer.allowRestrictedServices
- com.apple.BTServer.le
- com.apple.BTServer.programmaticPairing

Comment: sounds interesting, can you share a code that works with those entitlements ?

Comment: The code shown above should work. Just get the CBPairingAgent from your CBPeripheralManager and call unpairPeer: with the CBPeripheral* to remove.

Comment: I don't have JB device and can't check it. Maybe someone else will check it, thank you